# Serialize state containing non-Codable builtin types using custom logic

Tags: swift, cocoa, serialization

I'm working on a specialized PDF reader for RPG manuals. I'm using [ReSwift](https://github.com/ReSwift/ReSwift) for state management, and I need to serialize/deserialize each window's state.

Part of a window's state might naturally consist of non-`Codable` objects like [PDFSelections](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfselection). Right now, the state instead contains `Codable` structs that represent the same information, and I'm converting them back and forth as needed, but this is awkward and probably not very performant. I'd like to keep the “real” objects in the state and (de)serialize them only when needed (e.g. when saving/restoring the window's state).

I'm currently using JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder for serialization. However, some of the types I would like to serialize are not `Codable`, and I don't see a way to provide custom logic for non-`Codable` types. Is there a way to make this work with JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder? If not, is there an alternative approach that might work?

Comment: "However, some of the types I would like to serialize are not Codable, and I don't see a way to provide custom logic for non-Codable types." Can they be saved into `Data` and init from `Data`, ie is there a way to `CustomClass` <-`something`-> `(NS)Data`? If so, use that `something`.

Comment: Not sure I understand. All of my custom classes are `Codable`; it's the builtin ones like `PDFSelection` that are the problem.

Comment: Have you tried extensions? For example, did you add `extension PDFSelection: Codable {}` and then implemented the missing methods?

Comment: Yes, but you can't implement `Decodable` in an extension of a non-final class because the `init` would have to be marked `required`. Other than that, it would be the perfect solution.